# Updating certain column values of rows with similar columns on the other rows

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, while-loop, do-while

How do I update a pandas dataframe column value of a row, if 2 of its columns are the same as the other row?

For example:

[image]

Say if I have a script that updates User 1's Need to 5 on index 0, then User 1's need on index 3 will also be 5 since they both have same **ITEM** and **USER**?

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'STORE': ['Store_1', 'Store_1', 'Store_1', 'Store_2', 'Store_2', 'Store_2'],
              'ITEM': ['oranges', 'oranges', 'oranges', 'oranges', 'oranges', 'oranges'],
               'AVAILABLE': [5, 5, 5, 13, 13, 13],
              'USER': ['1', '2', '3', '1', '5', '4'],
               'NEED': [1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3]})

df
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `loc`:

```
user = '1'
new_val = 5

# Broadcast value to rows where USER is '1'
df.loc[df['USER'] == user, 'NEED'] = new_val
print(df)

# Output
     STORE     ITEM  AVAILABLE USER  NEED
0  Store_1  oranges          5    1     5
1  Store_1  oranges          5    2     3
2  Store_1  oranges          5    3     2
3  Store_2  oranges         13    1     5
4  Store_2  oranges         13    5     2
5  Store_2  oranges         13    4     3
```